# What shall be the hash/range keys in dataset like the following to avoid GSI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
id   date     locationId   comment  type
1    2017-01  DSE374HD2    asdf     a
2    2017-01  DSE374HD2    qwer     a
3    2017-02  DSE374HD2    wer      b
```

So ideally I wanted to set locationId as the hash key and date as sort key but then realised that this won't work as it overwrites values since the hash key need to be unique within the table.

Then I chose id as the hashkey and added a global secondary index with locationId as hash and date as range keys. I think this could work however this comes with increased costs as the gsi provisioning is separate, so I'd waste 1 read and 1 write for the main table since I'd need to add additional provisioning for the gsi as far as I know.

Do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the volume of data the table may get per day.
You can try that:

Partition Key: LocationId

Sort Key: data#id or data#id#type 
(you can put any name to it, for example, 'CombinedSortKey')

When you will push data for your sort key, do a string concatenation to combine multiple values in it. So, the value may look like this:

```html
locationId CombinedSortKey
DSE374HD2  2017-01#a#1
DSE374HD2  2017-01#a#2
DSE374HD2  2017-02#b#3
```

And, when you will scan or query the table, you can use comparison or function to your sort key to filter out the data you need.

Check this page for [comparison and function details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).